# Adding a new row with data to excel sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding a new row to a table but want to then add the data to that row that I just added.   I am thinking something like this, but not sure how to add each columns data to that new row.  My table has 4 columns named "store" "emp#" "date" & "amt".  I have specific data that I will put in each column.  I simplified the code, as there is a whole lot more to the macro, but just stuck on this part.  Thank you for you help.

```
Dim rt_ws As Worksheet
Dim rt_tbl As ListObject

Set rt_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RT Clock Hours")
Set rt_tbl = rt_ws.ListObjects("rt_hours")

With rt_table.ListRows.Add

    .  `this is where I am not sure what to do`
    .
    .

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RT Clock Hours")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("rt_hours")

    With tbl.ListRows.Add
        .Range = Array("Store1", "1530", "05/03/2020", "Amt1")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think `.Resize` is redundant. Shouldn't the `.Range` property of the `ListRow` object already be the same column size as the Table?